# Kalman filter or moving average?

Tags: kalman-filter

I want to track a single non-stationary real valued variable that increases over time using a Kalman filter. However, I don't know the expected measurement/process/ error covariance apriori.

Is it a bit of an overkill to use a Kalman filter? I had hoped it would do a better job than guessing appropriate parameters for a moving average. However, after playing around with a couple of [examples](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/filter.html), it seems to be quite sensitive to incorrect measurement/process covariance assumptions.